# no matching artifact paths found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am planning to build a sample .net mvc application using AWS codebuild.
But getting an error : *no matching artifact paths found*

buildspec.yml file given below.

what am I missing?
[image]

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Executing Install Phase

  pre_build:
    command:
      - echo Executing Pre Build Phase
      - echo Restore started on `date`
      - echo restore demorepo2.csproj

  build:
    command:
      - echo Executing Build Phase
      - echo build started on `date`
      - dotnet publish -c release -o ./build_output demorepo2.csproj 


  post_build:
    command:
      - echo Executing Post Build Phase


artifacts:
    files:
        - ./build_output/**
    name: build-demo2-artifacts
```

Comment: Shoudn't it be `build_output/**/*`?

Comment: I even tried that but no luck.

Comment: So can just output everytihing `- '**/*'`, go to s3 and download the artifact archive. With this you can inspect it what exactly it contains.

Comment: good suggestion marcin. I did that but it does not contain 'build_output' folder. When i use 'dotnet publish -c release -o ./build_output demorepo2.csproj'  on my local machine then it creates build_output folder and it contains all the DLLs. Unable to understand why build_output folder not present on S3.

Comment: So you know now why you get this error. Probably your `donnet` has problems?

Comment: add `ls -la` as a new command after the `dotnet` command to see what it produces.

Comment: In the log, BUILD status is a success. So I think the application is getting build successfully. But don't know why its not able to create ```build_output``` folder.

Comment: Can't help with `donnet`. Haven't used that. It's strange it doesn't work. There are no messages from it in the codebuild logs?

Comment: ```Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
Expanding build_output/**/*
Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED
Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching artifact paths found``` only this error.

Comment: I mean log from the build process. It should be very log which contains all the `echo` command outputs.

Comment: added log screenshot in the question post, please have a look.

Comment: There are mistakes in your buildspec.yml file. It should be `commands`, not command. Also the output from the log does not even match the buildfile you posted here. You are executing different file then what you posted.

Comment: Damn!!! You are correct. Is should have been `commands`. Now it working fine. This mistake cost me a whole day. Thank you very much for this @Marcin. Cheers!!

Comment: No problem. Glad its working. I will make answer for future reference.

Comment: hey @Marcin, using `code deploy` I am able to copy artifacts from S3 to EC2 instance at `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder. But when i am trying to access this website from my local machine i am getting a default IIS website. Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Seems like a new issue. Maybe worth making new question with new details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments. The issue was an **incorrect statement** in the `buildspec.yml` file. Instead of `command` it should be `commands`.